# Change of voice via ffmpeg or other application

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, voice

I have a set of audio files containing voice recordings, I need to alter the voice signal so the speaker cannot be recognised in an automated way...
*Do you know some application?*

Answer (score 2):

Audacity can do what you want.

Comment: Can i run Audacity in batch mode?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to apply effects to the voice so that it becomes unrecognizable ? You can use SOX (http://sox.sourceforge.net/) for that. Note that law enforcement will be able to "undo" any effects you have added.